# fine on Nexus 5x, double vision on Pixel

Tags: aframe, webvr

Using A-frame, on Nexus 5x my scene looks fine. However on Pixel the content in one of the eyes is too far apart, making the image double vision when headset on. Does anyone know a fix for this? Could it be the larger screen?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for testing that. The issue probably belongs on Google's WebVR polyfill, https://github.com/googlevr/webvr-polyfill, we can file an issue there, and I'm sure it'll get fixed promptly!

Comment: Thank you :) that'd be excellent! Let me know if there's anything else regarding the Pixel and a-frame I can test

Comment: Also filed at https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/2117